# bash wildcard completion

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

Is it possible to make bash expand wildcards on tab completion in the same style as zsh?

So imagine the following:

```
mkdir new
touch new/1.txt new/2.txt new/3.log
```

Now,

```
ls new/*.txt<TAB>
```

Would expand to

```
ls new/1.txt new/2.txt new/3.log
```

BUT `ls new/` should not expand but should instead list potential matches (no wildcard).

`M-*` gets close but isn't quite there. If you try the above in zsh you will see the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I think you looking for <kbd>C-x *</kbd> (`glob-expand-word`).  I've never used zsh, but see if that does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `set -o vi` then you can use `<ESC>-*` to expand wildcards, but it's instead of, not at the same time as pressing tab.